# How to disable resizing of a UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to:

1. Disable resizing for this usercontrol.  In other words, when the user grabs the corners or the sides of this usercontrol with a mouse, I dont want the user to be able to  change the size of the usercontrol?
2. Or if there is no way to stop resizing then how do I only allow the right side of the usercontrol dragged?

```
  <UserControl x:Class="MyEditor.MyDialog"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="152" d:DesignWidth="590" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=VariableType}" MinHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Grid Width="591" Height="147" MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=VariableTypeTextBox}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="137*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="454*" MinWidth="250" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" Margin="0,94,7,0" Name="CancelButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="CancelButton_Click" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Content="Create" Height="23" Margin="0,94,108,0" Name="CreateButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="CreateButton_Click" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Variable Name " Height="28" Margin="0,12,29,0" Name="VariableName" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="96" Target="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
    <TextBox Height="29" Margin="0,11,7,0" Name="VarNameTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHandler" LostFocus="LostFocusHandler" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Label Content="Variable Type" Height="28" Margin="0,0,29,73" Name="VariableType" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="96" />
    <TextBox Height="23" Margin="0,51,7,0"  Name="VariableTypeTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" Background="Silver" Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Width="AUTO" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You've pasted the XAML for a `UserControl`, but your question is asking about a `Window`. So, you will need to place your UserControl inside a Window that is set up to not allow resizing.

A WPF Window has a ResizeMode property, which can be one of the following:

- NoResize
- CanMinimize
- CanResize (default)
- CanResizeWithGrip

You will want NoResize.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="MyEditor.Views.EditorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyEditor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Title="Editor Window">
    <views:MyDialog />
</Window>
```

Please see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Resize_Mode) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I did put n my qyestion User Control as well.

Comment: Would it work to place your UserControl in a Window, as I've shown in my answer?

Comment: It crashes all over becasue in the code I created a UserControl but now I am creating a Window.  If there was a way to make the user control not resizeable that would be the desired path.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You talk about the user performing a resize by grabbing the sides/corner of the *user control*, but user controls don't have resizing capability, only windows do. So, there must be a window somewhere in your app that contains your user control. If you want to completely prevent the user from resizing your application window, you need to enforce that at the window level. If you just want your user control to be a fixed size, you can set it's MinWidth/MaxWidth and MinHeight/MaxHeight, but this will not prevent the user from shrinking the window so far that it covers up your user control.

Comment: I was invoking a Window to invoke my UserControl  :

    Window window = new Window
                    {
                        Title = "Create New Activity Variable",
                        Content = new NewVariableDialog(activity,modelService, _editor.SelectedVarTypeOnInspectorPane ),SizeToContent= SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight, ResizeMode= ResizeMode.NoResize

                        
                    };

                   
                    window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen ;


                    window.ShowDialog();

Comment: So I used  DanM ResizeMode = NoResize and it works.   @DanM:  Thank you very mych for following up to resolve the issue and thanks for  the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the MinWidth/MaxWidth and MinHeight/MaxHeight properties to your required value.

Comment: Thank you. I set the Max and Min for the UserControl but That does not work.

Answer (score 2):

For Disabling : ResizeMode="CanMinimize"

```
<Window x:Class="XXXXXX.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XXXXXXX"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
        Title="Window">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Window)Parent).ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
}
```

Or an attached property on the UserControl if you use the Prism Library:

```
<prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStartupLocation" 
            Value="CenterScreen" />
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
        <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False"/>
        Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight"/>
    </Style>
</prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
```

Comment: This prevents the resizing of the parent window but the OP wanted to prevent the UserControl itself from resizing. Moreover, this assumes that the parent of the UserControl is the Window, which may not be the case.

Comment: @Optimax: The question seeks to prevent the user from resizing the UserControl using the mouse at runtime. The UserControl MUST be hosted in a Window for this to happen. The runtime user cannot access the UserControl directly. My suggested solution is therefore valid. An alternative solution would be to add an attached property on the UserControl as shown in my additional answer.